# Read pixel color with foreach_get() on image data

Tags: python, image

I tried filling a numpy array with the foreach_get() method on an image, but get the following error:
*foreach_get/set() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)*

```
def read_pixels(img):
    resolution = img.size[0] * img.size[1]  
    colors = np.zeros(resolution*4, dtype=np.float)
    img.pixels.foreach_get("pixels", colors)
    colors = np.reshape(colors, (resolution, 4))
    return colors
 
img = bpy.data.images['TestImg.png']
print(read_pixels(img))
```

foreach_get() should take 2 arguments, doesn't it? The name of the attribute ('pixels') and the array to be filled?!

Comment: I'm not sure, but you call `foreach_get` method on the `pixels` object, so the method uses its `self` argument which is set automatically to the `pixels` object. From what I could google, other people use `foreach_get` by only passing the numpy array as a temporary buffer, so you should try `img.pixels.foreach_get(colors)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**"The python console check"**

In case Markus is busy can get a lot of info using autocomplete <kbd>Tab</kbd> in the python console, with an image as `img`

```
>>> img.pixels.foreach_get(
foreach_get(seq)
.. method:: foreach_get(seq)
This is a function to give fast access to array data.
```

which is plainly different from, for instance a mesh `me` vertices, which asks for an attribute `attr` , *eg* for vert coordinates `"co"`

```
>>> me.vertices.foreach_get(
foreach_get(attr, seq)
.. method:: foreach_get(attr, seq)
This is a function to give fast access to attributes within a collection.
```

A very slight improvement in speed can be attained by using `np.empty` to initialize the array, since any garbage  will be filled by the foreach get.

```
import time
import numpy as np
    
REPS = 100

def time_it(func):
    def wrapper(*arg, **kw):
        t1 = time.time()
        for i in range(REPS):
            func(*arg, **kw)
        t2 = time.time()
        print(func.__name__, (t2 - t1))
    return wrapper

@time_it
def read_pixels(img):
    resolution = img.size[0] * img.size[1]  
    colors = np.zeros(resolution*4, dtype=np.float32)
    img.pixels.foreach_get(colors)
    colors = np.reshape(colors, (resolution, 4))
    return colors

@time_it
def read_pixels2(img):
    x, y = img.size
    pixels = np.empty(x * y << 2, dtype=np.float32)
    img.pixels.foreach_get(pixels)
    return pixels.reshape((x, y, 4))

@time_it
def nptest1(img):
    x, y = img.size
    return np.array(img.pixels, dtype=np.float32).reshape((x, y, 4))
    
@time_it    
def nptest2(img):
    x, y = img.size
    return np.array(img.pixels[:], dtype=np.float32).reshape((x, y, 4))

import bpy
for img in bpy.data.images:
    nptest1(img)
    nptest2(img)
    read_pixels(img)
    read_pixels2(img)
    #break
```

Results

```
nptest1 8.4240
nptest2 7.0605
read_pixels 0.2264
read_pixels2 0.2222
```

Note on posting noticed I had reshaped to image x, y, 4, however reshape is an almost time "free" method, will get back if otherwise.  (Got a squeak more using bitwise shift to quadruple)

Answer (score 3):

as Markus von Broady pointed out, ommiting the attribute name and just passing the numpy array works. Thank you.

I was confused, because specifying the the attribute name worked in other areas, e.g.

```
sculpt_vertex_colors[name].data.foreach_get('color', colors)
```

But I guess that's a different structure.
Had to change the dtype to float32 instead of just float.
Here is the corrected example

```
def read_pixels(img):
    resolution = img.size[0] * img.size[1]  
    colors = np.zeros(resolution*4, dtype=np.float32)
    img.pixels.foreach_get(colors)
    colors = np.reshape(colors, (resolution, 4))
    return colors
 
img = bpy.data.images['TestImg.png']
print(read_pixels(img))
```