# How to override render result in blender python?

Tags: python, rendering, image

Working on a script and I need a way to update the render result image to a modified render result image.

As far as I've seen, accessing pixels and other properties requires you to save out the render image on disk and reload it again, but I haven't found a way to modify the original render result or change it to another image altogether.

I've some addons that do that (AI render for example I think uses compositor), just wondering if there's a decent way to achieve this?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!!

Comment: Hello ! This should help https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/252521/86891 and this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/214469/read-pixel-color-with-foreach-get-on-image-data

Comment: Sorry to be clear, the issue I'm having is permission related, not modifying pixel values.
As far as I've tried, I couldn't find a way to write any info to render result image, can't set the image to anything else either.
Basically I can create a new image with the changes I wanted, but the goal is to set it to render result for further processing either through compositor or etc.

Comment: @Gorgious, the `bpy.data.images['Render Result'].pixels` array has a length of zero once the render is complete.  It's unclear how those links help when they rely on having data in the `pixels` array.  Could you clarify?