How could I speed up pixel iteration and evaluation?
I'm writing a script which finds the highest and lowest red values of a given image. Here's the code:
img = a loaded image file

pixels = list(zip(*[iter(img.pixels)] * 4))
reds = [r for r, g, b, a in pixels]
r_min = min(reds)
r_max = max(reds)

This code is slow, taking more than 4 seconds for a 4k image. I thought I could speed it up by only considering every nth pixel so I tried this:
step = 10
reds = [r for i, (r, g, b, a) in enumerate(pixels) if i % step == 0]

but this runs even slower than the first solution.
How could I improve this code to be as performant as possible?

Hello. Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/214469/read-pixel-color-with-foreach-get-on-image-data

Try numpy as suggested by Gorgious. Here is an example that uses the numpy.min and numpy.max functions:
import bpy
import timeit
import numpy as np

image_name = 'test.jpg'   # must be opened in Blender

def print_image_info():
    img = bpy.data.images[image_name]
    resolution = img.size[0] * img.size[1]    
    print(f"image resolution: {resolution} pixels, ({img.size[0]} * {img.size[1]})")


def testFunc():

    img = bpy.data.images[image_name]

    pixels = list(zip(*[iter(img.pixels)] * 4))
    reds = [r for r, g, b, a in pixels]
    r_min = min(reds)
    r_max = max(reds)
    
    print(f"r_min: {r_min}, r_max: {r_max}")
    return r_min, r_max


def testFunc_v2():

    img = bpy.data.images[image_name]
    
    resolution = img.size[0] * img.size[1]
    colors = np.zeros(resolution*4, dtype=np.float32)
    img.pixels.foreach_get(colors)
    colors = np.reshape(colors, (resolution, 4))
    
    rgba_min = colors.min(axis=(0))   # min values of all 4 channels (RBGA) 
    rgba_max = colors.max(axis=(0))
    
    print(f"rgba_min: {rgba_min}, rgba_max: {rgba_max}")
    return rgba_min, rgba_max


def testFunc_v3():
    img = bpy.data.images[image_name]
    resolution = img.size[0] * img.size[1]
    colors = np.empty(resolution * 4, dtype=np.float32)
    img.pixels.foreach_get(colors)
    red_values = colors[0::4]    # slice to get only R values
    
    red_min = red_values.min(axis=None)  
    red_max = red_values.max(axis=None)
    
    print(f"red_min: {red_min}, red_max: {red_max}")
    return red_min, red_max


print_image_info()
print("--- v1 (original) ---")
print("time v1: ", timeit.timeit(testFunc, number=1))
print("--- v2 (numpy) ---")
print("time v2: ", timeit.timeit(testFunc_v2, number=1))
print("--- v3 (red channel only) ---")
print("time v3: ", timeit.timeit(testFunc_v3, number=1))

It's about 4x faster and calculates the min and max for all 4 channels at once. Test with a 30M pixel image:
r_min: 0.0, r_max: 0.9764706492424011
time v1:  7.681219500023872
image resolution: 30105600 (4480 * 6720)
rgba_min: [0. 0. 0. 1.], rgba_max: [1.         0.97647065 0.97647065 1.        ]
time v2:  1.598861699923873

Another run:
r_min: 0.0, r_max: 0.9764706492424011
time v1:  8.123031500028446
image resolution: 30105600 (4480 * 6720)
rgba_min: [0. 0. 0. 1.], rgba_max: [1.         0.97647065 0.97647065 1.        ]
time v2:  2.197276199935004

Update: If you are only interested in one channel and need the performance you can drop the other channel data. To do this, slice the numpy.array with the red_values = colors[0::4] syntax. This creates a view that starts with element 0 and includes every 4th element, i.e. all R values of an RGBA array. 'View' means that the original data is not moved or copied, so it is really performant.
Updated test run (on other PC):
image resolution: 20250000 pixels, (6000 * 3375)
--- v1 (original) ---
r_min: 0.12156863510608673, r_max: 0.7372549176216125
time v1:  3.4206019999983255
--- v2 (numpy) ---
rgba_min: [0.12156864 0.14509805 0.16470589 1.        ], rgba_max: [0.7372549  0.74509805 0.8000001  1.        ]
time v2:  0.7799248000083026
--- v3 (red channel only) ---
red_min: 0.12156863510608673, red_max: 0.7372549176216125
time v3:  0.0661091999936616

Related questions:

Read pixel color with foreach_get() on image data
Stackoverflow: Extracting minimum values per row using numpy
Stackoverflow: extract every 4th elements from the numpy array [duplicate]


Thank you for the in-depth answer and examples!
Would there be any benefit in extracting and evaluating only the red channel?

Yes, I think you can make it a bit faster if you only interested in the red channel values. The reading the data is already fast, most of the time is used for the statistics. If you only have 1/4 of the data then it should be 4x times faster, right? Let's see...

Surprisingly, it is indeed much faster if you only process the values of the red channel, about 10 times than v2, and about 60x faster than the original script :-) Just as an aside, I also used a for loop for testing and that took minutes :D

Awesome! Thank you so much for all your help. It's really invaluable!
